# The process order of SQL order by, group by, distinct and aggregation function?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, aggregate, aggregation

Query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT max(age), area FROM T_USER GROUP BY area ORDER BY area;
```

So, what is the process order of order by, group by, distinct and aggregation function ?

Maybe different order will get the same result, but will cause different performance. I want to merge multi-result, I got the sql, and parsed.So I want to know the order of standard sql dose.

Comment: distinct is just a special kind of group by

Comment: if the distinct is specified, so there is no group by ?

Comment: it's redundant. remove it, and you'l get the same result, because you already told it group by area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bigger than just group by/aggregation/order by. You want to have an sense of how a query engine creates a result set. At a high level, that means creating an execution plan, retrieving data from the table into the query's working set, manipulating the data to match the requested result set, and then returning the result set back to the caller. For very simple queries, or queries that are well matched to the table design (or table schemas that are well-designed for the queries you'll need to run), this can mean streaming data from a table or index directly back to the caller. More often, it means thinking at a more detailed level, where you roughly follow these steps:

1. Look at the query to determine which tables will be needed.
2. Look at joins and subqueries, to determine which of those table depend on other tables.
3. Look at the conditions on the joins and in the where clause, in conjunction with indexes, to determine the how much space from each table will be needed, and how much work it will take to extract the portions of each table that you need (how well the query matches up with your indexes or the table as stored on disk).
4. *Based the information collected from steps 1 through 3*, figure out the most efficient way to retrieve the data needed for the select list, regardless of the order in which tables are included in the query and regardless of any ORDER BY clause. For this step, "most efficient" is defined as the method that keeps the working set as small as possible for as long as possible.
5. Begin to iterate over the records indicated by step 4. If there is a GROUP BY clause, each record has to be checked against the existing discovered groups before the engine can determine whether or not a new row should be generated in the working set. Often, the most efficient way to do this is for the query engine to conduct an effective ORDER BY step here, such that all the potential rows for the results are materialized into the working set, which is then ordered by the columns in the GROUP BY clause, and condensed so that only duplicate rows are removed. Aggregate function results for each group are *updated* as the records for that group are discovered.
6. Once all of the indicated records are materialized, such that the results of any aggregate functions are known, HAVING clauses can be evaluated.
7. Now, finally, the ORDER BY can be factored in, as well.
8. The records remaining in the working set are returned to the caller.

And as complicated as that was, it's only the beginning. It doesn't begin to account for windowing functions, common table expressions, cross apply, pivot, and on and on. It is, however, hopefully enough to give you a sense of the kind of work the database engine needs to do.